# Rails, Nginx, Passenger, SSL - File Uploads Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, nginx, passenger

I am not able to get uploads to work with Passenger-Nginx and SSL. Uploads work fine if I disable SSL.

Here is my Nginx site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.in;
    root /home/deploy/mysite/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_user deploy;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mysite.in;
    root /home/deploy/mysite/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_user deploy;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/www_mysite_in.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.key;

    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    #Disables all weak ciphers
    ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # Specifies that server ciphers should be preferred over client (e.g. browser) ciphers when using SSL/TLS.
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
}
```

Any config/environments/production.rb

```
Mysite::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
end
```

I have tried disabling the `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'` and it makes no difference under SSL or non-SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get this to work. So I just deleted the VPS image, and created a new one... and it works.

PS - I was using a setup script to install all the packages, so I am at a total loss as to why it didn't work with the original VPS image.